# write_delim() putting quotation marks around html code

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, df, that contains html code:

```
df <- structure(list(pmid = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"), 
    html = c("<a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/\" target=\"_blank\">Stack Overflow</a>", 
    "<a href=\"https://www.google.com/\" target=\"_blank\">Google</a>", 
    "<a href=\"https://www.amazon.co.uk/\" target=\"_blank\">Amazon</a>"
    )), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

> df
  pmid                                                                    html
1  ID1 <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>
2  ID2            <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>
3  ID3          <a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/" target="_blank">Amazon</a>
```

However, whenever I write this to a .xls file using [write_delim](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readr/versions/1.3.1/topics/write_delim), it puts quotation marks around the html code:

```
write_delim(df, "df.xls", delim = "\t", quote_escape = "none")
```

And when I look at the df.xls file, it looks like this:

```
pmid    html
ID1 "<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>"
ID2 "<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Google</a>"
ID3 "<a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/" target="_blank">Amazon</a>"
```

Why does this happen, and is there any way to prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

> `quote_escape`    The type of escaping to use for quoted values, one of "double", "backslash" or "none". You can also use FALSE, which is equivalent to "none". The default is "double", which is expected format for Excel.

Maybe you're overengineering it? If you leave the default, the quotes should be escaped appropriately